# Body background fluke - white space on top

Tags: css

This is really weird. When this page is viewed in FF, it gets a white stripe on top which is part of body - I know because I use red border technique to see the elements.

Any ideas why?
http://www.codecookery.com/allbestimages/index.php?main_page=home

Comment: got it, had to set padding/margin to 0.

Comment: The link is 404 now, and without it, this question could do with closing (it's not going to help any future readers). Could you add your own vote to close, sarsnake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set padding/margin to 0.

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

```
#main-page-body-wrapper{
  height: 0px;
}
```

or set the background color to black. I checked it out in chrome and firefox. Used firebug and the chrome inspect element tool. This is not the body that is creating the white space but the #main-page-body-wrapper element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `#slideshow` element is positioned absolutely. This removes it from the normal page flow and therefore your `#main-page-body-wrapper` is essentially empty and just sitting at the top of the page.

I suggest you avoid absolute positioning unless you're really, really sure you need it. I'd recommend making a few changes. First of all get rid of the absolute positioning:

```
#slideshow {
    height: 541px; /* Height of the slideshow */
    position: relative;
    /* Remove width, left, top and margins from here */
}
```

`position: relative;` in the above block sets the current position as the starting point for any child elements that are absolutely positioned (such as your slideshow images). If this doesn't make sense then check out:

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

You don't need `width: 100%` on divs and other block-level elements because that is the default so remove that:

```
#main-page-body-wrapper  {
    /* Remove width from here */
    text-align: center; /* IE6 centering Part 1 */
}

#main-page-inside-wrapper  {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    width: 1000px; /* Width of the slideshow */
    text-align: left; /* IE6 centering Part 2 */
}
```

I don't see why you should need `#content-wrapper` inside `#main-page-inside-wrapper` - it doesn't look like it's doing anything. You should try to keep your HTML as simple as possible to avoid mess and confusion; You only really need 2 divs to do cross-browser centering like you're doing so I'd get rid of `#content-wrapper` if I were you.

This is by no means a complete solution but should help you get to where you're going. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for recommendations. 
Extra divs are added because this page is part of Zen cart software, so any layout changes for the index page are going to be in every page, it could of course be changed but the effort is not worth it. These divs are not doing anything but also are not harming anyone. 

As I said, I solved the issue.