# Margin 0 and fixed background cause weird border OR what?

Tags: css, background, attachment, margin, fixed

I am currently developing this site: [tochat.vn](http://tochat.vn)

As viewing in Firefox 7.0.1, it has annoying white border at top of the page. I have been trying to remove the border in many ways, but nothing really works.

Actually, there are 2 things I noticed,

1. when I removed "margin: 0" on body tag (on reset.css)
2. OR when I removed the "fixed" value of background-attachment of the "body" class (on style.css)

the border disappeared.

But I can't remove these attributes :(

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two posts seem to address similar issues, if not the issue itself:

- [Body background fluke - white space on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947947/body-background-fluke-white-space-on-top)
- [Strange border on fixed postition elements in firefox 7.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886848/strange-border-on-fixed-postition-elements-in-firefox-7-0-1)

Side Note: I went to the mentioned link in FireFox 7.0.1 and did NOT see a space and the background was fixed. The background was flush with the top left corner.

Did you fix the issue on the page that the link leads to?
Is this a wordpress installation with a custom theme?

Comment: At the time you visited, I haven't fixed it. Weird, really. And thanks for your link, I have it solved, by adding -moz-border-radius:0 1px to the .body class.

And it is Joomla, not Wordpress :)

Thanks again for your help.